Default date filter is not working in Sonata Admin Bundle
I have a list of users and I'm trying to set up a default filter on the createdAt attribute to get by default the users created in the last month rather than all the users at once.
Here's my current attempt:
Entity\User.php
#[ORM\Column(name: 'creation_date', type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
private ?DateTime $createdAt = null;

UserAdmin.php
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper): void
{
    $datagridMapper->add('createdAt', DateTimeRangeFilter::class, [
                'field_type' => DateTimeRangePickerType::class,
            ])
    ...
}

protected function configureDefaultFilterValues(array &$filterValues): void
{
    $filterValues['createdAt'] = [
        'value' => [
            'start' =>  (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 month')->format('M d, Y, h:i:s a'),
            'end' => (new \DateTime())->format('M d, Y, h:i:s a'),
        ],
    ];
}


Is your current attempt succeeding or failing? If it's failing, is it getting an error or just returning incorrect data? It would be helpful to refine the question title too, to something more detailed than "not working".

It was a formatting issue. Between the seconds and the 'am/pm' there was a special character (Narrow No-Break Space) which was f-ing up the whole filter.
My code ended up like this :
protected function configureDefaultFilterValues(array &$filterValues): void
{
    $start = (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 month')->format('F j, Y, g:i:sa');
    $end = (new \DateTime())->format('F j, Y, g:i:sa');
    $filterValues['createdAt'] = [
        'value' => [
            'start' =>  (new \DateTime())->modify('-7 day')->format('M d, Y, h:i:s a'),
            'end' => (new \DateTime())->format('M d, Y, h:i:s a'),
            'start' =>  preg_replace('/(am|pm)$/', "\u{202F}\$0", $start),
            'end' =>  preg_replace('/(am|pm)$/', "\u{202F}\$0", $end),
        ],
    ];
}

